# can a function be used instead of event for ng model option

Tags: angularjs

Say I have some input tag with the following angular associated:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" data-ng-model='value.name'>
```

When a form with this tag gets submitted, it will update the value's name.

Is there a way to trigger `updateOn` when a function defined by the controller is invoked rather than an event? Or is the API only able to handle browser events?

For example:

if i have something like this:

```
angular.module('someModule')
  .controller('someCtrl', ["$scope", Callback])

function Callback($scope){
  $scope.updateValue = updateValue

  function updateValue(){
    console.log('will now update value')
  }
}
```

Is there a way to only update a model if the `updateValue` function gets invoked?

This won't work, but something like this?:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'updateValue' }" data-ng-model='value.name'>
```

Comment: Invoke the  [ngModelController $commitViewValue method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$commitViewValue) to commit a pending update.

Comment: so it's not specified in the example above, but I'm inside of an ng repeat scope, so i'm not sure that method will help me.

Comment: also, i'm guessing there not a way to leverage a function in these cases?

Comment: How is this question useful to other readers? What experience in being created for the user? What external event triggers the need to commit input values?

Comment: You can use updateOn with a value that will never happen (usually submit) and then do whatever you want to do and call `$commitViewValue()` as georgeawg suggested.

Comment: @georgeawg I wanted to add inline edit functionality. And wanted to revert a value back to its original value on cancel. But there is an intermediary confirm feature that updates it because it fires a submit.

Comment: Just save the original values and copy them back on cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a custom function into the `updateOn` property of the `ng-model-options` directive, however, you can have control over when things get pushed to the model, like so:

```js
angular.module('someModule', [])
  .controller('someCtrl', ["$scope", Callback])

function Callback($scope){
  $scope.updateValue = updateValue
  $scope.value = {
    name: ""
  }
  function updateValue(form){
    console.log('will now update value')
    // form.[prop] matches name="prop" attribute on form input
    form.name.$commitViewValue();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="someModule" data-ng-controller="someCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name"
           data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" data-ng-model='value.name'>
    {{value.name}}<br/>
    <button data-ng-click="updateValue(myForm)">Update Name</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but the problem was, I was trying to submit the value for a confirm step, and therefore firing the update. I ended up using another controller to copy my angular object to store it temporarily. It's feels a bit hacky, but as you said, you can't pass custom functionality into `updateOn`